# Controlling the USB from Windows

Tags: windows, usb

I know this probably is not the easiest thing to do, but I am trying to connect Microcontroller and PC using USB. I dont want to use internal USART of Microcontroller or USB to RS232 converted, its project indended to help me understand various principles.

So, getting the communication done from the Microcontroller side is piece of cake - I mean, when I know he protocol, its relativelly easy to implement it on Micro, becouse I am in direct control of evrything, even precise timing.

But this is not the case of PC. I am not very familiar with concept of Windows handling the devices connected. In one of my previous question I ask about how Windows works with devices thru drivers. I understood that for internal use of Windows, drivers must have some default set of functions available to OS. I mean, when OS wants to access HDD, it calls HDD driver (which is probably internal in OS), with specific "questions" so that means that HDD driver has to be written to cooperate with Windows, to have write function in the proper place to be called by the OS. Something similiar is for GPU, Even DirectX, I mean DirectX must call specific functions from drivers, so drivers must be written to work with DX. I know, many functions from WinAPI works on their own, but even "simple" window must be in the end written into framebuffer, using MMIO to adress specified by drivers. Am I right?

So, I expected that Windows have internal functions, parts of WinAPI designed to work with certain comonly used things. To call manufacturer-designed drivers. But this seems to not be entirely true becouse Windows has no way to communicate thru Paralel port. I mean, there is no function in the WinAPI to work with serial port, but there are funcions to work with HDD,GPU and so.

But now there comes the part I am getting very lost at. So, I think Windows must have some built-in functions to communicate thru USB, becouse for example it handles USB flash memory. So, is there any WinAPI function designed to let user to operate USB thru that function, or when I want to use USB myself, do I have to call desired USB-driver function myself? Becouse all you need to send to USB controller is device adress and the infromation right? I mean, I don´t have to write any new drivers, am I right? Just to call WinAPI function if there is such, or directly call original USB driver. Does any of this make some sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your life easier, and avoid writing your own driver, try using the [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) (Human Interface Device) API on top of USB. Although it says "Human Interface", it doesn't actually have to be for devices that a human controls. The advantage is that modern OSes already come with a HID driver and you can use sample code such as what you can find [here](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm) to get started. Many microcontroller manufacturers provide suitable code for the embedded of the protocol.

Because OSes already understand HID, if you build a device using the HID interface you'll find that not only can you read from it from any OS, you may also find that many applications can already talk to your device if its communication is restricted to a small enough subset of HID. (For example, I built an input device for a music app, but amazingly I found I could literally plug it straight into a 3D animation app we use at work, running on a different OS, and have it work right away without writing a single additional line of code!)

Comment: Hi, thanks, can I have one more question? If I get it right, HID is actually WinAPI part to communicate with USB drivers, but still, USB drivers must have capability to send data to device and backwards. So can I adress USB drivers directly? I have actually never worked with something outside C standart library, WinAPI or .net classes.

Comment: There should already be a HID driver installed that knows how to do everything. (My experience is not on Windows unfortunately. I did some googling. Chapter 13 [here](http://proyectosfie.com/html/usb/libro/) is about HID on Windows.) I don't think you need to know anything about drivers, except that there is one present.

Comment: Thanks. Can I have ona more quick question? Lets say I have USB webcam and I want it to work with some WinAPI function thats designed to work with webcams. (even there is none, its just theory) So, would I write just some translator between WinPAI and some general USB driver(just call some send() function from USB driver), or would I have to write entire USB communication within my driver? By that I mean all the communication with USB controller?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652698/control-usb-ports) might aim you in the right direction.

[The first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981558/receiving-data-from-a-usb-device-in-c-or-c) might also be helpful.

[The answers to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935184/how-to-get-vendor-id-and-product-id-of-a-plugged-usb-device-on-windows) have some actual code and links to yet other resources.

Answer (score 0):

USB includes a set of stock functionality, much like supporting USB flash drives (USB Mass Storage class). The two most interesting for microcontroller interfacing are HID and CDC. CDC is easiest to use as it directly emulates an old fashioned serial port.

If you configure the microcontroller to act as a CDC device, Windows will enumerate it as a serial port, and all the old serial APIs will work on it.